# Suttas on the 5 Precepts

Tags: pali-canon, sutras, five-precepts

I am looking for the suttas where the Buddha has preached about the 5 precepts. Also how it can lead you to Samadhi, Niravana and etc.

-Metta

Answer (score 4):

The sutta below lists out the criteria for stream entry:

- Five forms of fear and animosity are stilled (basically the five precepts)
- Four factors of stream entry
- Rightly seen and rightly ferreted out the noble method (dependent origination)

The four factors of stream entry are verified confidence in the Buddha, Dhamma and Sangha, as well as, being endowed with the virtues appealing to the noble ones.

From the [Vera Sutta (AN 10.92)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.092.than.html):

> Then Anathapindika the householder went to the Blessed One and, on
>   arrival, having bowed down to the Blessed One, sat to one side. As he
>   was sitting there, the Blessed One said to him, "When, for a disciple
>   of the noble ones, five forms of fear & animosity are stilled; when he
>   is endowed with the four factors of stream-entry; and when, through
>   discernment, he has rightly seen & rightly ferreted out the noble
>   method, then if he wants he may state about himself: 'Hell is ended;
>   animal wombs are ended; the state of the hungry shades is ended;
>   states of deprivation, destitution, the bad bourns are ended! I am a
>   stream-winner, steadfast, never again destined for states of woe,
>   headed for self-awakening!'
>
> "Now, which five forms of fear & animosity are stilled?
>
> "When a person takes life, then with the taking of life as a requisite
>   condition, he produces fear & animosity in the here & now, produces
>   fear & animosity in future lives, experiences mental concomitants of
>   pain & despair; but when he refrains from taking life, he neither
>   produces fear & animosity in the here & now nor does he produce fear &
>   animosity in future lives, nor does he experience mental concomitants
>   of pain & despair: for one who refrains from taking life, that fear &
>   animosity is thus stilled.
>
> "When a person steals... engages in illicit sex... tells lies...
>
> "When a person drinks distilled & fermented drinks that cause
>   heedlessness, then with the drinking of distilled & fermented drinks
>   that cause heedlessness as a requisite condition, he produces fear &
>   animosity in the here & now, produces fear & animosity in future
>   lives, experiences mental concomitants of pain & despair; but when he
>   refrains from drinking distilled & fermented drinks that cause
>   heedlessness, he neither produces fear & animosity in the here & now
>   nor does he produce fear & animosity in future lives, nor does he
>   experience mental concomitants of pain & despair: for one who refrains
>   from drinking distilled & fermented drinks that cause heedlessness,
>   that fear & animosity is thus stilled.
>
> "These are the five forms of fear & animosity that are stilled.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, the suttas labeled "[Five Precepts](https://suttacentral.net/sn37.24/en/sujato)" are a bit short and lacking detail. We have, however, a longer discourse in [A Layperson AN 5.179](https://suttacentral.net/an5.179/en/sujato):

> [And what are the five precepts in which their actions are restrained? It’s when a noble disciple doesn’t kill living creatures, steal, commit sexual misconduct, lie, or use alcoholic drinks that cause negligence. These are the five precepts in which their actions are restrained.](https://suttacentral.net/an5.179/en/sujato)

And if you want a *really REALLY long discourse*, consult the [Analysis of the Precepts](https://suttacentral.net/vb14/en/thittila).